# how to setText() in android embedded card

Tags: android, xml, sqlite, android-layout

Here I have a nice simple table layout to display the contents of my database.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1">

    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Date"
            android:id="@+id/Date"
            android:layout_weight="0.3333"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Systolic"
            android:id="@+id/Systolic"
            android:layout_weight="0.3333"
            android:textAlignment="center" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Diastolic"
            android:id="@+id/Diastolic"
            android:layout_weight="0.3333" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/DateInfo"
            android:layout_weight="0.3333"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/SystolicInfo"
            android:layout_weight="0.3333"
            android:textAlignment="center" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/DiastolicInfo"
            android:layout_weight="0.3333" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Here is the method that is called in the onCreate of the calling activity:

```
private View buildView() {
    //CardBuilder card = new CardBuilder(this, CardBuilder.Layout.MENU);
    //card.setText("It worked!!!");
    CardBuilder previousReadings = new CardBuilder(this, CardBuilder.Layout.EMBED_INSIDE);
    previousReadings.setEmbeddedLayout(R.layout.blood_pressures);

    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.SystolicInfo);
    //tv.setText("Why won't this work?");
    MyDatabase info = new MyDatabase(this);
    info.open();
    String data = info.getData();
    info.close();
    System.out.println(data);
    //tv.setText(data);

    return previousReadings.getView();
    //return card.getView();
}
}
```

I used the CarBuilder object card that was a simple card without an embedded layout and this worked fine. I then commented it out and tried implementing the embedded card which also works fine (above). However the problem arises when I try to tv.setText(). Whether this is just a constant or the "data" variable. The logcat reads "unable to load Activity:... null pointer exception.

Can anybody shed some light on the problem? I have tried EditTexts as well as TextViews and neither work. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `previousReadings.getView()` call `findViewById` to access TextView from Card:

```
....
System.out.println(data);
View view= previousReadings.getView();
TextView tv = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.SystolicInfo);
tv.setText("Why won't this work?");
return view;
```

Comment: Thank you Prosper K!!! Just wondering, why do we need to declare a view to use findViewById() rather than just use the card?

Comment: @MichaelAndroidNewbie: we need to use layout view  to call `findViewById` from which we want to access view like if we have Activity and one Dialog  with some TextView's then we need to access Activity context to access views from Activity layout and Dialog view for access views from Dialog